# How to get a list of resource groups in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, resources, azapi

I want to get all resource groups in the subscription using Terraform.
The goal of it is to go through the storage accounts in these resource groups and create resources based on those storage accounts.

I've tried the following things but the list of resource groups is always empty:

```
data "azurerm_resources" "resource_groups" {
  type = "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups"
}
```

```
data "azapi_resource_list" "all_resource_groups" {
  // Get version from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.resources/resourcegroups?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#resource-format
  type                   = "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2022-09-01"
  parent_id              = "/subscriptions/${data.azurerm_client_config.current.subscription_id}"
  response_export_values = ["name"]
}
```

I also added an output to check the result and this is what it shows:

```
  + all_resource_groups = {
      + id                     = "/subscriptions/<redacted>/resourceGroups"
      + output                 = jsonencode({})
      + parent_id              = "/subscriptions/<redacted>"
      + response_export_values = [
          + "name",
        ]
      + timeouts               = null
      + type                   = "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2022-09-01"
    }
```

EDIT: Note that after getting the resource groups I'm going to filter them in a for loop so that only certain resource groups are included but the resource groups may not exist which is why it is necessary to fetch them first.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to get the list of resource groups in Terraform using cli commands in the null resource. I was able to provision the resource successfully.

I tried to use the module that you shared unfortunately that doesn't work. So I tried using the CLI commands which helped list out the resource group and place them in a null resource of terraform where I could list out resource group.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}


resource "null_resource" "resource_groups_list" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      az group list --query '[].name'--output json > resource_groups.json
    EOT
  }
}
```

**Output:**

command `Terrafrom Plan`

[image]

Command `Terraform Apply`

[image]

This command will create a **`json`**  with all the info related to resource groups available in the subscription.

Now run the command `cat resource_groups.json`

This will list out the available resource groups in the subscription.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I thought about doing this, too but this would require the Azure CLI to be available. I'd prefer a Terraform-only solution.

Comment: There are a few modules available in the Terraform registry but unfortunately, they are not working as expected. This can still be considered as terraform as we pass the code through a null resource using terraform.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer does not solve my problem. I don't want the list to be saved to the file system but rather use it in Terraform to perform the next steps. I tried using the data source `external` but it requires the JSON to be an object while the az CLI outputs an array, so that does not work. I'm not sure how `null_resource` can help here.

Comment: I understand your requirement as you need to achieve the list of resource groups. However, achieving it directly from Terraform is the tricky part as it was a third-party application trying to fetch this particular resource. we can fetch the data from the list of subscriptions and the List of resources inside a resource group but listing the available resource group under subscription is tricky using Terraform.

Comment: I understand that. Maybe an issue needs to be created on the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the parent (the subscription)? I managed to fetch a list of Azure Container Apps using the resource, then parsing the output and creating new resources based on the exported attributes.

```
data "azapi_resource_list" "container_apps" {
  type                   = "Microsoft.App/containerApps@2022-11-01-preview"
  parent_id              = "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/resource-group-name"
  response_export_values = ["*"]
}

locals {
  # this creates map {<id>: <name>} containing the apps, suitable for for_each
  aca_apps = {for app in jsondecode(data.azapi_resource_list.container_apps.output).value: app.name => app.id }
}

module "some_module" {
  for_each             = local.aca_apps
  source               = "../_modules/some_module"
  name                 = "app-name-${each.key}"
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. My question has an example just like yours but when using resource groups as the type, nothing is returned in the list.